# Jenkins, how we can update the SVN url password at a time for all projects

Tags: svn, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins (in linux machine) and SVN, and we've configured almost 40 jobs.

and for every 45 days i need to change my system (local machine, windows) password, so at this time i also need to change my SVN URL password for all 40 jobs, Since my local machine password is my SVN URL password.

so when ever i change my password it will automatically updates the SVN.

so is there any way where i can configure my password in one place, so that all jobs SVN url will point to that ???

Thanks,
Karthik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get this plugin installed.

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Credentials+Plugin

---

With this plugin you update your credentials once - and use it everywhere in jenkins.

[image]